# JCheckbox change the text position

Tags: swing, position, jcheckbox

How do i change the position of the text in JCheckbox.
I want the text to be on the left of the check box and not as default on the right.
i been over the jcheckbox, jtooglebutton and jabstractButton api few times.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
jCheckBox.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

It's actually inherited from [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalTextPosition%28int%29), but you can find this also for [JLabels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalTextPosition%28int%29) (in this case, it's relative to the icon you may use in the label).

Now this is assuming you want just a particular change on this one component. If your goal is to reverse the direction of all components in your application (for example for a right to left reading), you should probably look into component orientation, with the [setComponentOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29) and [applyComponentOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#applyComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29) methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this within Netbeans IDE select HorizontalTextPosition and change to leading[JCheckBoxProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK1Hx.png)